# Looking for an object database

Tags: .net, database, object

I'm looking for an object database for .NET that is open source and free for commercial use. I need something that is available as assemblies and/or source code to embed into a project, i.e. not a stand alone database in its own process.

I am aware of db4o, and it would be perfect except for the commercial license coming at a price.

ACID transaction support is desirable, but I really just want to know what options are out there.

Comment: Can you expand on your requirements?  Types of objects, what sorts of queries, volume of data, need for ACID transactions, etc?  Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I wrote that I'm not sure. My mistake. Didn't know what's object db

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IMO the one you mention (db4O) is easily head and shoulders the best OODBMS out there. It simply just works how you expect, has Linq support and perf is very good. It is also free for you in development mode and free for use in open source projects.

And...for commercial use the licence is very attractive, typically you only pay on a (very small) percentage basis of your revenue. IMO for a commercial product it's totally worth it, your customers will also have the comfort of knowing your database solution is backed by someone like Versant and not some potentially forked or abandoned Open Source solution.

I know that you want free all the way, but honestly you will give up a lot for that, and the small price you'll pay for db4O (after you are making already making money from it) will be totally worth it.

(I do not have any affiliation with Versant or db4o, apart from being a very happy user)

Comment: db4o lost my support when i couldn't find any dollars and cents licensing info on their site and when I read this post and it said "Percentage basis of revenue".

Answer (score 7):

Give a try to Eloquera Database (www.eloquera.com)
It's FREE for commercial use and native .NET object database.

Answer (score 1):

I think that eloquera (www.eloquera.com) is better than db4o and additionally has better licensing. For instance, Eloquera is free for commercial use and db4o not (db4o has the same licensing options than mysql, free for free but paid for commercial use).

For this and technical things I think Eloquera is better.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of objects do you need to store?  One possibility is [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), which lets you store documents containing JSON-like key-value pairs.  There's [a C#/.NET driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/C+Sharp+Language+Center).

Comment: Thanks, but I believe MongoDB runs in its own process? I was after something that builds into my .NET app.

Answer (score 0):

Try Scalable Object Persistence (SOP) framework from http://www.4atech.net!

Comment: Please tell us more about it.